# Is there a standard way to store XY data in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, standards

Is there a *standard* way to store (x,y), (x,y,z), or (x,y,z,t) data in Python?

I know NumPy arrays are used often for things like this, but I suppose you could do it also with NumPy matrices.

I've seen the use of two lists zipped together, which side steps the use of NumPy altogether.

```
XY_data = zip( [x for x in range(0,10)] , [y for y in range(0,10)] )
```

Is there a *standard*?  If not, what is your *favorite* way, or the one which you have seen the most?

Comment: Are you asking about spatial coordinates specifically, or any arbitrary data?

Comment: For me, I am asking about spatial coordinates.  However, I am sure that if you have any information about either the internet community will be happy to learn.

Comment: A side note: `[x for x in range(0,10)]` is identical to simply `range(10)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One nice way is with a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  This gives all the advantages of NumPy arrays, but it has a convenient access structure.

All you need to do to make your NumPy array a "structured" one is to give it the `dtype` argument.  This gives each "field" a name and type.  They can even have more complex shapes and hierarchies if you wish, but here's how I keep my x-y data:

```
In [175]: import numpy as np

In [176]: x = np.random.random(10)

In [177]: y = np.random.random(10)

In [179]: zip(x,y)
Out[179]:
[(0.27432965895978034, 0.034808254176554643),
 (0.10231729328413885, 0.3311112896885462),
 (0.87724361175443311, 0.47852682944121905),
 (0.24291769332378499, 0.50691735432715967),
 (0.47583427680221879, 0.04048957803763753),
 (0.70710641602121627, 0.27331443495117813),
 (0.85878694702522784, 0.61993945461613498),
 (0.28840423235739054, 0.11954319357707233),
 (0.22084849730366296, 0.39880927226467255),
 (0.42915612628398903, 0.19197320645915561)]

In [180]: data = np.array( zip(x,y), dtype=[('x',float),('y',float)])

In [181]: data['x']
Out[181]:
array([ 0.27432966,  0.10231729,  0.87724361,  0.24291769,  0.47583428,
        0.70710642,  0.85878695,  0.28840423,  0.2208485 ,  0.42915613])

In [182]: data['y']
Out[182]:
array([ 0.03480825,  0.33111129,  0.47852683,  0.50691735,  0.04048958,
        0.27331443,  0.61993945,  0.11954319,  0.39880927,  0.19197321])

In [183]: data[0]
Out[183]: (0.27432965895978034, 0.03480825417655464)
```

Others will probably suggest using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), but if your data is relatively simple, plain NumPy might be easier.

You can add hierarchy if you wish, but often it's more complicated than necessary.

For example:

```
In [200]: t = np.arange(10)

In [202]: dt = np.dtype([('t',int),('pos',[('x',float),('y',float)])])

In [203]: alldata = np.array(zip(t, zip(x,y)), dtype=dt)

In [204]: alldata
Out[204]:
array([(0, (0.27432965895978034, 0.03480825417655464)),
       (1, (0.10231729328413885, 0.3311112896885462)),
       (2, (0.8772436117544331, 0.47852682944121905)),
       (3, (0.242917693323785, 0.5069173543271597)),
       (4, (0.4758342768022188, 0.04048957803763753)),
       (5, (0.7071064160212163, 0.27331443495117813)),
       (6, (0.8587869470252278, 0.619939454616135)),
       (7, (0.28840423235739054, 0.11954319357707233)),
       (8, (0.22084849730366296, 0.39880927226467255)),
       (9, (0.429156126283989, 0.1919732064591556))],
      dtype=[('t', '<i8'), ('pos', [('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])])

In [205]: alldata['t']
Out[205]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [206]: alldata['pos']
Out[206]:
array([(0.27432965895978034, 0.03480825417655464),
       (0.10231729328413885, 0.3311112896885462),
       (0.8772436117544331, 0.47852682944121905),
       (0.242917693323785, 0.5069173543271597),
       (0.4758342768022188, 0.04048957803763753),
       (0.7071064160212163, 0.27331443495117813),
       (0.8587869470252278, 0.619939454616135),
       (0.28840423235739054, 0.11954319357707233),
       (0.22084849730366296, 0.39880927226467255),
       (0.429156126283989, 0.1919732064591556)],
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])

In [207]: alldata['pos']['x']
Out[207]:
array([ 0.27432966,  0.10231729,  0.87724361,  0.24291769,  0.47583428,
        0.70710642,  0.85878695,  0.28840423,  0.2208485 ,  0.42915613])
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not seen this before.  So essentially using both zipping and numpy arrays together creates a different datatype called a structured array?  
What is the advantage of pandas over numpy?

Comment: I have not yet used pandas, but it is a bit more powerful for doing lots of different grouping and filtering on your datasets.  If you are familiar with numpy methods and find them lacking, look to pandas, but I would start with plain numpy.  Others will disagree of course :)