# How to store X-Y data in order to use the functions in Numpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scientific-computing

Both **Numpy** and **Scipy** have a number of useful functions for performing operations on data (i.e. integrating, Fourier transforms, baseline correction, etc.). However, I haven't seen documentation regarding the general form for inputing X-Y data into these functions. Say I have a spectrum of wavelength and absorbance values, or stress and strain data from a mechanical properties test.

Does one generally:

1. Use two 1-D Numpy arrays, one for X, and one for Y?
2. Use one 2-D Numpy array, with X on one axis, and Y on the other?
3. Use a single [structured array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815999/is-there-a-standard-way-to-store-xy-data-in-python)?

How does this change when you have XY-Z data?

What is the most general data structure for XY data that allows me to input my data directly into *most* of these functions without redefining how I store my data?

Comment: From what I have seen, generally 2D array with the columns representing the X, Y, Z, etc., specially with Scipy.

Comment: So go for __Option 2__, the 2-D (2 x N) array approach.

Comment: Generally speaking that's what I would suggest.

Comment: Use the approach that best solves your problem. That being said, going from 2 -> 1 is very easy, ie `x, y = twoByN_array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the documentation for each package and operational class or function.  `scipy` is a collection of packages, written by different people, and often serving a interfaces to even older Fortran or C packages.  So the input format is constrained by those sources.  And they also depend on what is suitable for the problem.

Often it is convenient to generate values on a regular grid.  For example use `np.meshgrid` or `np.mgrid` with `arange` or `linspace` values to define a 2d space.  The result can be 3 2d arrays - the `x` and `y` values, and the `z` as a function of those.

But realworld data is often available as scatter points.  Each point is then a `x`, `y` location with a `z` value.  You can't cast those as 2d arrays, at least not without interpolation.  So three 1d arrays is the appropriate representation.  Or a `(n, 3)` matrix, one column for each of the variables.  Or if the values have different dtype - say integer for x and y, float for z, then a structured array with 3 fields.

Often data is loaded from csv files - the columns representing those `x,y,z` values, maybe with string labels, and multiple `z` values.  With a mix of data types they are often loaded with `genfromtxt`, resulting in a 1d structured array.

It's easy to map from structured arrays to multiple arrays with uniform dtype.  Sometimes you do this by just indexing with the field name, other cases might require a `view`.

To delve into this more you might need to expand on the data type(s), and the packages that you need to use.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata.  `interpolate.griddata` illustrates the use of both point data and grid data.

Comment: Well, that pretty much tells me that the answer it no. I was hoping that being new to Numpy/Scipy I just didn't pick up on the standards, but it seems like, as you said, there aren't any because Scipy is an incoherent collection by various authors. It sounds like constantly re-arranging your data to fit each functions argument type is the norm.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not an answer to your question, know that if you work with only two or three dimensions you can easily switch from one standard to the other thanks to
`XYZ =  np.column_stack((X, Y, Z))` and `X, Y, Z = XYZ.tranpose()`.

Usually they are both fairly cheap operations compared to the rest of your data analysis.